# Python Selenium is_displayed() returns true and ElementNotVisible exception is still raised?

Tags: python, selenium

Before calling any of the element's send_keys(), I first check if it's enabled and visible so it doesn't raise an exception.

What happens is is_Displayed returns True and when I try to send_keys to that element it still raises an exception of ElementNotVisible. Is this some form of a bug?

It works on some websites, it doesn't work on another.

```
def login():
 elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name, "user")]')
 for elements in elem:
  if elements.is_displayed():
   if elements.is_enabled():
    elements.send_keys(username)
    elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name, "pass")]')
    for elements in elem:
     if elements.is_displayed():
       if elements.is_enabled():
        elements.clear()
        elements.send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)   #Crashes here
        time.sleep(4)
        return
```

Comment: Only idea I have `Keys.RETURN` imitate the pressing of `BACK` browser button. Why do you need it there?

Comment: It's supposed to simulate Enter button. It works and logged me in some sites.

Comment: My bad, you right. Did you try to split `elements.send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)` into two commands `elements.send_keys(password)` and `elements.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` and look for where it crashes.

Comment: Yea I did, it seemed to crash less often when I separated the two. So I included them together that way.

Comment: Also you can try `Keys.ENTER` instead of `Keys.RETURN`. Dunno what is a difference, but it can help :)

Comment: <input style="display: none;" class="textbox" tabindex="102" name="vb_login_password" id="navbar_password" size="10" type="password">    thats the problematic input

Comment: `style="display: none;"` says it is not visible

Comment: May be it becomes invisible after `clear()` ?

Comment: Crazy Web-Application there xD

Comment: Unfortunately this fixed a problem and raised new ones. Some fields on other websites have by default "Password" value in them and I need it cleared. I am going to try selecting the control and send a tons of back space keys to clear it instead of clear()

Comment: Bad approach. It is better to check the value by `getAttribute` and if it is not empty use `clear()`.

Comment: Well it didn't work anyway and sending backspace caused it to raised ElementNotVisible exception again. I am gonna go get some rest then I am gonna wake up and figure out how to force selenium to launch the original firefox instead (it keeps launching Palemoon instead for some reason) then I am going to adjust browser to not execute javascript because I think it's behind all of this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def login():
 user_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name, "user")]')
 for user in user_elements:
  if user.is_displayed():
   if user.is_enabled():
    user.send_keys(username)
    pass_elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name, "pass")]')
    for passw in pass_elements:
     if passw.is_displayed():
       if passw.is_enabled():
        passw.clear()
        passw.send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)   #Crashes here
        time.sleep(4)
        return
```

It's likely your choice of variable names make you clobber the outside loop with the inside loop.

Comment: Thanks your for answer but I fixed my problem by launching a different firefox profile with javascript disabled and it fixed the issue. So it seems some javascript code in that specific website was causing the trouble.

Comment: Such a pity - I'm now going to wonder about this for weeks to come. *sigh*

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still wondering what problem was, it was caused by javascript hiding element after page was fully loaded.

Completely disabling javascript on page solved that issue.

Answer (score -1):

pls use my code, my github https://github.com/big-vl/isdisplayed_selenium/blob/master/isDisplayed.py

```
def isDisplayed():
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='find text vwhis in page']")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True

    #use function

if (isDisplayed() == True):
    print('text find, pleas replace hash tag or replace xpatch')
else:
    print('not found text, my style php/python *smile*')
```